# Erro em NamedQuery

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, jpa

Boa noite pessoal, estou querendo criar uma `namedquery` com uma consulta no banco.
Segue:

```
@NamedQuery(name="ListagemProdutosMesa",query="select Produto p FROM Produto p, Pedido pe, Conta c, Pedido_produto pp  where pe.id = pp.pedido_id and pp.produto_id = p.id and c.id = pe.conta_id and c.id=:idConta")
```

Onde essa tabela `Pedido_produto` é a tabela criada só para referenciar as chaves estrangeiras( acho que o problema esta aí).

O engraçado é que essa `query` roda de boa direto no `Postgres` e no `Java` está dando erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar???

Comment: Qual erro? Como está mapeada sua tabela de Produto no Java?

Comment: Amigo, obrigrado por responder. Consegui resolver já. Como eu estava mapeando em java eu nao estava pensando como objetos, segue a query: @NamedQuery(name="ListagemPedidoMesa",query="select pe.produto from Pedido pe, Conta c where c.id = pe.conta.id and c.numeroMesa =:nMesa and c.situacao = false")

Comment: Coloca como resposta da sua própria pergunta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já consegui resolver!
Como eu estava mapeando em Java eu nao estava pensando como objetos, segue a `query`:

```
@NamedQuery(name="ListagemPedidoMesa",query="select pe.produto from Pedido pe, Conta c where c.id = pe.conta.id and c.numeroMesa =:nMesa and c.situacao = false")
```